# UIApplicationSignificantTimeChange equivalent on Apple Watch

Tags: ios, uiapplication, watchos-3

According to the [respective documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsnotification.name/1623059-uiapplicationsignificanttimechan), `UIApplicationSignificantTimeChange` notification is not available on `WatchOS`. Is there an equivalent notification or way to be notified about significant time changes (new day mainly) on an Apple Watch app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK there is no built in equivalent in WatchKit. However, you should be able to create an equivalent using [UNCalendarNotificationTrigger](https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications/uncalendarnotificationtrigger) and setting the trigger to the next day each time a new notification is delivered.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, I could indeed do that but I would prefer to avoid the burden of managing an extra notification for something (seemingly) as simple as that. I'll wait a bit in case someone has a more straightforward approach that we've missed.